# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext doesn't return retina image

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I want to capture current screen in an image. I'm doing this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Problem is the scale parameter. If I understand correctly 0.0 represents non-retina, 2.0 represents retina and 3.0 represents retina for 6 Plus and 7 Plus. No matter what I input into the scale parameter, the output is always image with 375x667 resolution. I also tried different approach:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
self.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let snapshot: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Again, same scenario. I'm even using

> UIScreen.main.scale

Which in fact returns value 2.0. What am I doing wrong? How do I get a higher resolution image?

Comment: Actually, 0.0 means the actual screen's scale, not non-retina. That's 1.0.

Comment: How are you determining the "size" of the resulting image?

Comment: What does "resolution" mean? The only thing that would differ is the resulting UIImage's `scale`. Size is measured in points, not pixels; it is the same for all scales.

Answer (score 2):

This code will do the trick

```
let contextSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width * UIScreen.main.scale, height: self.view.bounds.size.height * UIScreen.main.scale)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contextSize, self.view.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
self.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let snapshot: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

**[CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext)** don't care about scale, it care about size only.

**EDIT**

You may want to use the newer API available in iOS 10 and later

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: self.view.bounds)

let snapshot = renderer.image(actions: { context in
    self.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
})
```

Comment: That just did this: http://i.imgur.com/hKXsmkY.jpg (blue is the captured screenshot)

Comment: Try passing **0** as scale

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Try using **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextSize)** instead of **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**

Answer (score 0):

**snapshot** is a `UIImage` which has two properties, `size` and `scale`; much like the screen. To determine the actual size in pixels of the image you must multiply the the size by the scale. I think your issue is that you're assuming the size property is pixels not points.

> [**size**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624105-size)
>   The logical dimensions of the image, measured in points.

You can test this in a very definitive way by creating a JPG using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and saving it to disk to inspect using image tools you're familiar with.